# How do I continue using AdMob and support SDK 4+?

Tags: android, admob

I received an email informing me that I must update to Google Mobile Ads SDK 7.  However this requires min-sdk to go up to 9.  I previously had 4.  Is there a way I can upgrade and still people with older android versions be supported.  As it is now, everyone who uses an older version of android (or does not update) will be able to use my app ad-free.

Comment: You could use a version check and just don't let the app load if it's on a version that's too old. I'm not sure how to do this on android, but I'm sure it's possible

Comment: there is no direct way to achieve this. Way we have achieve similar condition is release an update for all ( including version 4 ) where check for date and after that date they have to upgrade android OS or start using version 9 +.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. And you don't worry about it.

API versions 9 and below are less than 0.1% of the market.
Give you app away for free to that mall portion as good will and spend your time increasing the value of your app for the rest of the market.